# How do I view the full description of a room in chat?

Tags: support, chat

There are a number of chat rooms that I would like to view the description for, but unfortunately the description is truncated in the room list, and I can't figure out where to find the full description. Where can I find this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No need to enter the room to see its full description.

In the chat lobby (rooms list), each room has "info" link:

> [image]

Clicking each will open a page with details about the room, including full description:

> [image]

You can also middle click each link to open in different tab, so that you'll have several open in the same time.

Answer (score 2):

It's visible in the sidebar in the chat room itself. Note that the sidebar isn't visible on the mobile-web version of chat.

You can also find it at chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/info/roomid/room-name.